Namespace Issue in the cloud datastore
I upgraded the Java from 8 to 11 and using the namespace from the Objectify 6.1.1. When I am storing the data in the different namespace then the data is being stored in the different namespace as intended. But the issue is it is not showing the value in the namespace section in the cloud datastore. When I log the Namespace using
com.googlecode.objectify.NamespaceManager.get(); 

it is showing correctly in logs that this particular data is being stored under this namespace but the Namespace is not showing in its section. What could be the possible issue with that. Here is the attached snapshot where the namespace is not being shown(https://i.sstatic.net/Jfwd05I2.png)
here is the code snippet for this
code for logging the namespace
logged here:logs for depicting
There are previously present namespaces which has the data but new namespace is not being persisted over there.
This issue is being occurring at the stagging environment, and it is working properly in the development environment. I have checked by creating couple of users in the staging env and the namespace is being logged in the logs but is not persisting/showing in the namespace drop down menu. I have checked for the Dashboard where all the namespace are being shown and the namespace is also not there.

What do you mean by Namespace is not showing in its section?

I'm working on a SaaS library management system where each library's data (books, borrowing, queueing) is stored in its own namespace. The system logs show that books are being added to the correct namespace. However, in the staging environment, newly added namespaces are not appearing in the dropdown menu, even though they show up correctly in the migration environment. How can I resolve this?

Are you sure you're running the code in the right env? Your responses imply you have different env. Is it possible that this env (where you have the issue) has the wrong code? You should also update your question and include the snippet of code where you add a record to a specific namespace. This will help others figure out if the issue is from your code.

Thank you for your support, I can be able to see the namespace in the dropdown menu (as shown in the image on the question). May be the cloud datastore took time to reload the things, if you have some insights on this please share.
